# Logging to rails console with rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rakefile

I have a rake file that is being called by a job scheduler. The file outputs the desc but I am not able to log anything else to the console. What am I missing?

inbox.rake

```
namespace :inbox do
  desc 'Check inbox for new app builds'
  task process_inbox: :environment do
    puts "my task is working"  
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`puts` sends the text to `STDOUT`, which is different when you run `rake` from the terminal versus invoking from another ruby process.

Where do you expect to see this text?

Comment: I would like to see it in the rails logger and/or as the output of `rake -T inbox`

Comment: By "rails logger" do you mean "log/development.log"?  Or do you mean in the output from the `rails s` process?

Comment: output from `rails s`

Comment: it's not going to show up there.  If you use `Rails.logger.info` in your rake task and it is invoked in a separate process, you'll see it in the log file, which you can see with `tail -f log/development.log`.

Comment: nothing is being written to the log by the task for `Rails.logger.info` nor `puts`

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Heroku logs, you need STDOUT to see the outputs. Could be as simple as

```
my_logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
my_logger.info "work or die"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try manually printing to console.

```
namespace :inbox do
  desc 'Check inbox for new app builds'
  task process_inbox: :environment do
    Rails.logger.info "my task is working"  
  end
end
```

Comment: Not working. Using this instead: http://jerryclinesmith.me/blog/2014/01/16/logging-from-rake-tasks/

Answer (score 1):

You're not using --quiet / --silent are you?

Comment: Not that I know of. How would I check?

Comment: When you execute rake, do you include any of those parameters? Also if you can provide the full command line, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: No, no options params